# Select unbolded text & change its colour (of a selected paragraph)- MS Word VBA Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

- I would like to select a piece of text in MS Word 2010 document.
- Then using a macro: select the unbolded text & change the colour of that text to blue

NB: I don't want to do this to the whole of the document text, just to the paragraph/block of text I have selected)

Picture demonstrating what I would like to do:

[image: pic]

I have tried creating the following macro - but it for some reason makes all of the text (bolded and unbolded) blue

```
    Sub MakeUnboldedTextBlue()
'
' MakeUnboldedTextBlue Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Bold = False
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Font.Color = 15773696
End Sub
```

Update:
I would also like to exclude the bullet symbols from 'cyanizisation' (if possible)

For example:
[Example of the bullet symbols not being cyanized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thw1C.png)

Answer (score 0):

You look through every character in the selected text, then colour it if it isn't bold:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CyanizeNonBoldInSelection()
    Dim oRange As range
    Dim oChar As range
    Dim oListFormat As ListFormat

    Application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord "CyanizeNonBoldInSelection"

    Set oRange = Selection.range

    For Each oChar In oRange.Characters

        If oChar.Bold = False Then

            oChar.Font.ColorIndex = wdTurquoise

            If oChar.ListParagraphs.Count > 0 Then
                Set oListFormat = oChar.ListParagraphs(1).range.ListFormat
                oListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(oListFormat.ListLevelNumber).Font.ColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            End If

        End If
    Next oChar

    Application.UndoRecord.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! I've got one more request if possible. If I want to 'cyanize' non bold text excluding bullet point, is that possible?

Comment: If oChar.Bold = False And oChar.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListBullet Then

Comment: Thanks, however it doesn't quite work as I wanted. The change suggested means any text alongside a bullet point is not 'cyanized' (whether bolded or unbolded). I want all unbolded text cyanized, just not the bullet symbols. Apologies for the hassle, if my request is possible somehow please let me know? I've edited the original post with a picture to illustrate this.

Comment: Oh you mean the bullet itself should be cyan?

Comment: No, the bullet should be black/remain whatever color it originally was. Eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thw1C.png. The change you recommended (If oChar.Bold = False And oChar.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListBullet Then) basically prevents any text next to a bullet point being cyanized.

Comment: It might not be the most optimized way to do it, but for every character is made bold, I check if it has any listparagraphs (= there is by definition only one), then if so, I get the ListLevel object via the ListLevelNumber, whose Font.ColorIndex can in turn be set